Can a modified bitumen top layer hang suspended in the air over the gutter?
I recently had a modified bitumen roof installed on my house. During installation, the roofer extended the top layer of bitumen over the gutter and created a slight slope for drainage. However, this extension is not attached to anything and simply hangs suspended in the air:

I'm concerned about the long-term viability of this approach. Specifically, I'm worried about the following (and other things I might be unaware of):
Wind Damage: Strong winds could potentially lift the suspended bitumen extension.
Moisture Issues: Water might seep under the joint between the bitumen and the wall.
Cracking: The exposed bitumen might dry out excessively over time, causing premature cracks.
My question is:  Is extending the bitumen over the gutter and leaving it unsupported an acceptable installation method for a modified bitumen roof?

I'm not a roofer, however I have seen the MB installed like that a number of times.
